# How to select multiple div id's that begin with string with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the snippet below, $modal is undefined because there are multiple form instances.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var $modals = $(".update-form");
    var $form = $("#program-update-form-{{ form.instance.uuid }}");

    $modals.on("hide.bs.modal", function() {
      $form.trigger("reset");
    });

  });
</script>


<html>
  {% for id in form.instance.uuid %}
    <div id="program-update-modal-{{ form.instance.uuid }}" class="update-form">
  {% endfor %}
</html>
```

I think what I'm wanting to do is here is gather all program-update-modals and trigger a reset on the hide.bs.modal action.  The number of form instances is going to be dynamic and obviously the uuid's will be dynamic so I need to know how in jQuery to just grab all the div id's beginning with 'program-update-modal-'.  Open to other suggestions as well.

Comment: When/how is "hide.bs.modal" triggered? This isn't a standard event

Comment: This is precisely what classes are for. Add a class name to the elements you'd like to group.

Comment: @Dropout if I use the class name, will $modal.on() line still work?

Comment: @BenjaminDonnaloia it should IMO.. `$modal.on(...)` binds the event handler onto the element. If you change the selector to a class selector, i.e. `$(".some-class")` it should bind the event to each of the elements.

Comment: @Dropout, I have updated the OP with your suggestion, does this look like what you are saying?

Comment: Yes, now it selects with classes.

Answer (score 1):

Use the built in *starts with* selector.  https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

```
var divs = $("div[id^='program-udpate-modal']");
```

Answer (score 0):

For collecting all the divs with the common ID pattern, just query for all DIVs and then filter, then iterate over them all and put them namewise into a Javascript object

```
var PUMDivs = {}

var divs = $("DIV").filter(function(elem) {
  return elem.id.indexOf("program-update-modal-") == 0;
}).each(function(idx, elem) {
  PUMDivs[this.id.substring("program-update-model-".length)] = elem;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $form = $("[id^=program-update-form-]");

$modals.on("hide.bs.modal", function() {
  $form.trigger("reset");
});
```

To get all the elements starting with "program-update-form-" you should use: